# If I pass the parameter value to the checkbox, then the input value of the checkbox does not go to the Jenkins stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

properties([gitLabConnection(gitLabConnection: 'GitLab Connection', jobCredentialId: ''), [$class: 'GitlabLogoProperty', repositoryName: ''], parameters([extendedChoice(multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'choice', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'mongo, mysql', visibleItemCount: 10)])])

pipeline {
agent any[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSUin.png)

```
stages {
    
    stage('mongo') {
        when {
             expression { choice == 'mongo' }
        }
        steps {
             echo "${params.choice}"
        }
    }
    
     stage('mysql') {
        when {
             expression { choice == 'mysql' }
        }
        steps {[enter image description here][1]
             echo "${params.choice}"
        }
    }
}
```

}

[When I select both mongo and mysql checkbox then both stage should work but both stage mongo and mysql are skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSUin.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the extendedChoice Parameters setup in the declarative pipeline. Instead, I used Boolean Parameters. Please refer to the following for your use case. Note I have declared a global variable named choice.

```
def choice = ""

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Get details") {
            steps{
                
                timeout(time: 300, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                script {
                    // Select the product image
                choice = input message: 'Please select the product', ok: 'Build',
                                    parameters: [
                                    booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'mongo'),
                                    booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'mysql')]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Echo') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "::: Product : ${choice}"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('mongo') {
          when {
               expression { return choice.get("mongo") }
          }
          steps {
               echo "MONGO"
          }
      }
      
       stage('mysql') {
          when {
               expression { return choice.get("mysql") }
          }
          steps {
               echo "MYSQL"
          }
      }
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo 'The process is successfully Completed....'
        }
    }
}
```